# Issues with cross-compiling and "as"?

Tags: debian, compiling, arm, assembly

I'm trying to compile source for a utility for an ARM system (host machine: x86_64, Debian, `uname -v` reports version as "Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u1") but when it tries to pack the file into a final binary for use on the target system, I receive an error:

```
as: unrecognized switch -EL
```

I noticed I had two different binaries of `as`; one in `/usr/bin` and one in `/bin`. I renamed the one in `/usr/bin` as the copy in `/bin` has support for the `-EL` switch, but now I'm getting a new error:

```
as: unrecognized switch: --64
```

The previous as binary has support for this switch, even though it doesn't have support for `-EL`.

I'm fairly sure this is just an issue of not having the right version of `as`, but I don't know where to go get the right version. I've updated all the `gcc` and similar packages through apt-get, but this hasn't fixed the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you have binaries with the same name in `/usr/bin` and in `/bin`, they should be the same. Usually one would be a symlink to the other. It seems like a part of your cross compiler was installed over the existing tools. This will only result in confusion.

The program `as` is usually part of `binutils`, not `gcc`.

If you compiled the cross compiler yourself, you should make sure you don't overwrite the native utilities.

Comment: @Rafriedi is raising a very interesting concern, the OP seems to have mixed the native and the cross-compiling toolchain.

Comment: I didn't add any packages before I noticed that. That was how it was when I installed Debian.

Comment: I have the latest version of `binutils` (2.28-5) as reported by `apt-get`.

Comment: (Why can't I edit comments?) After reinstalling `binutils`, I'm back to the original  `-EL` error.

Comment: How did you get your cross compiler? Installed from package, or compiled yourself?